# Access store from effect with ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I need to access the store state from an effect in order to use a service and filter a property in the store.

I've read about an operator called *withLatestFrom* but I have not had any success using it.

How can I access the store in my filterTransports effect?

```
constructor(private store$: Store<fromFundamentalData.State>) {}


@Effect() filterTransports$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fundamentalDataActions.FundamentalDataTypes.FilterTransports),
    mergeMap((action: fundamentalDataActions.FilterTransports) => this.filterTransportsService.filter(action.payload, action).pipe(
        map((transports: any) => (new fundamentalDataActions.FilterSuccess(transports))))
    ));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like:

```
@Effect()
shipOrder = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<ShipOrder>(ActionTypes.ShipOrder),
  map(action => action.payload),
  concatMap(action =>
    of(action).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getUserName)))
    )
  ),
  map([payload, username] => {
    ...
  })
)
```

For more info see [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this)

Comment: Won't this trigger emissions each time the selector changes as well as when `ShipOrder` actions come in? What's the best way to handle this if you only want the state at the time when this effect runs?

Comment: Woops, great catch xander. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Do you mind explaining why the use of `concatMap` here works to solve the problem I described? To my understanding it's because the outer `of(action)` will complete

Comment: I've typically gotten around this problem by doing something like `mergeMap(() => this.store.pipe(select(someSelector), take(1))) ...`